# No call to onStartCommand() follows the restart of a crashed service in Android 2.3

Tags: android, service, restart

I have a problem with Android service restart. I am building against API version 7 and running on a device with Android 2.3.3.

The problem is, that when my service is killed by the system and is later restarted, only the `onCreate()` of my service is called. code in `onStartCommand()` is not executed. If I start my application for the first time, the code in `onStartCommand()` is normally executed and all works fine, until system kills my service, then the service will not restart correctly.

[Documentation says that `onStartCommand()` is always called when a service is restarted.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY) In the case of service restart, the `onStartCommand()` should be called with null intent. This is not my case.

Any idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You might be seeing a bug in Gingerbread. There was a thread in the android-developers group about it: [onStartCommand bug thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/d87fb390c13d141d/52f7154ab49f229?hl=en&q=dianne+hackborn+onstartcommand+bug#)

See the post numbered 26 by Dianne Hackborn for details.

Comment: thank you. so i have to duplicate initialization code in onCreate and in onCommandStart, because it is a widget...

Comment: Could it be possible that this is still a bug in 4.2.2?

Comment: It should be fixed in 4.2.2 according to the issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12117&can=1&q=onstartcommand&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Android 2.3 (API level 9), which got fixed in API level 10.

From Dianne Hackborns [post regarding this issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2H-zkME9FB0/ZymfmZTDaAkJ):

> Okay, this did indeed break in 3.3. [sic!]  The change was from August of
>   last year.  This is the change that broke it:
>   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5474b0f8603ee66413c3e44600ca46f162f3089e

Note that the git commit link previously did not work. [Click here for a working mirror link to the commit and line that is causing the bug.](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/5474b0f8603ee66413c3e44600ca46f162f3089e#L1L8220)

Also she meant 2.3, but wrote 3.3. [She later corrected it and provided a suggestion for a workaround:](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2H-zkME9FB0/KfJJq1RxLwUJ)

> Sorry yes I meant 2.3.
>
> This has been out in the code base since the GB code was released, so
>   there will be who knows what devices that ship with it.
>
> The problem is *not* that services are not being restarted, **just that
>   their onStartCommand() is not called with null at that time.  The
>   onCreate() method is still called.**  As a work-around, you could
>   probably just post a message in onCreate() and set a flag in
>   onStartCommand(); if you haven't received an onStartCommand() by the
>   time the message is processed, then you probably aren't going to get
>   the null Intent call.  (If you need to do this at all...  generally
>   for things like registering receivers, you really really want to do
>   this in onCreate(), since that method is only called once.)

She [also wrote](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-developers/2H-zkME9FB0/ZymfmZTDaAkJ) that this behavior will be fixed in the next platform update (post-3.0):

> I'll get this fixed in the next platform update (post-Android 3.0);
>   unfortunately this code has been out in the source tree for a while,
>   and in a couple releases now, so we'll need to live with the broken
>   behavior on those versions. The service will still have its onCreate()
>   called so you can do work there.

I assume the API level she meant was 10, **and I can confirm that `onStartCommand()` is called with null intents after a service restart when you switch from API level 9 to 10.**

Comment: I've observed that this was reproducible in API level 10 (2.3.6) too. However was NOT reproducible in API level 14.